# Can't connect to SQL Server only when running from VS2017

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have a Winform application that runs fine when I use the exe in the Debug or Release folder. But as soon as I run it from within VS2017 (both Debug and Release) it can't connect to SQL Server.

Connection string:

```
Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=true;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;
```

SQL Server error:

> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

I followed the directions given here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified/

Didn't work.

I tried disabling Firewall on both client and server. Still nothing.

The problem wasn't there at first, but then it started coming sometimes, and now it's 9/10 times.

My colleague also have the same problem when running the program in his VS2017.

The connectionstring is saved in the the `app.config` file.

Edit: tried with both DNS name and IP. Same error.

Comment: The two PCs are not in the same user group.  A remote PC connecting to a server will be put into a guest account any you would need to give access to the database for guests.  I prefer to use windows credentials in the database instead of SQL server credentials.  I normally create a group account on both local and server.  The put all users of the database into the group account.  Finally I change the database to use the windows group account for credentials.   Then change connection string to use Integrated Security=true;

Comment: I bet several thousand developers would say "no repro", because *nobody* would be able to work if there was such an issue. If there was a protocol issue you wouldn't be able to connect at all. Are you using a config transformation perhaps? Is SQL Server Express actually running?  *Did* you try connecting to port 1433? Does your firewall only allow *out*going connections from your application perhaps?

Comment: @jdweng user groups have nothing to do with *servers*. Are you talking about workgroups perhaps? If the computers are in the same domain you don't need to define multiple groups or accounts.

Comment: As I stated in the first text the program runs fine on my PC when I just execute the exe in the bin-folder. The problem ONLY occurs when I run in VS2017.

Comment: Domains only apply to corporate networks where group policy applies.  Where group policy doesn't apply groups are needed to be setup.  Workgroups are part of group policy.  My answer was a general answer and didn't specify the type of group.

Comment: @jdweng This is in a domain as Im working within a corporate network. But as I stated, the program works fine when running outside of VS2017.

Comment: The talk to your MIS about the Group Policy.

Comment: @jdweng What GPO? It seems like you aren't reading what I wrote. The connection works fine outside VS2017. The problem ONLY occurs when running from VS. And it doesn't occur 1/10 times I run the app. So I'm almost certain it can't be a security issue as it gets through sometimes.

Comment: Is the database really using the Username/password or is it using Windows Credentials?  Usually when I see issues like this it is with the Windows Credentials.  In a Corporate Network the windows credentials are verified through a password server.  So if the time to authenticate the password is delayed you will get intermittent results.  There may be routing issues to the Password Server or the password server is overloaded so I would still talk to the MIS people.

Comment: @jdweng But shouldn't I have the same problem when I run the exe then?

Comment: Try changing connection string to following From : SERVER\SQLEXPRESS To: \\SERVER\SQLEXPRESS